# THREE.js A and D movement in first person controls

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to make a first person controls prototype from scratch in THREE.js. I have successfully got the front and back movements working but I cant get my left and right (a, d) movements working. I tried adding and subtracting 90 degrees from the view angle, and then finding the sine and cosine values of it. but it doesnt work.

I was thinking of moving the player on tangent but  dont think thats right and dont know how to do it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>THREEJS</title>
 <style>
  body {
   margin: 0;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/96/three.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  let width = innerWidth
  let height = innerHeight

  let scene = new THREE.Scene()
  let camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, width / height, 0.1, 1000)

  let renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true })
  renderer.setSize(width, height)
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement)
  
  let cube = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1), 
   new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ color: 0x00FF00, wireframe: false }))
  let plane = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.PlaneGeometry(20, 20, 20, 10),
   new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ color: 0xFFFFFF, wireframe: false }))
  let light = new THREE.PointLight(0xFFFFFF, 1.5, 20)

  plane.rotation.set(-Math.PI / 2, 0, 0)
  cube.position.set(0, 1, 0)
  light.position.set(0, 10, 0)

  scene.add(cube)
  scene.add(plane)
  scene.add(light)

  addEventListener("resize", () => {
   width = innerWidth
   height = innerHeight
   renderer.setSize(width, height)
   camera.aspect = width / height
   camera.updateProjectionMatrix()
  })

  camera.position.set(0, 1, 0)

  renderer.domElement.onclick = () =>
   renderer.domElement.requestPointerLock()
  document.addEventListener('pointerlockchange', lockChangeAlert, false);
  document.addEventListener('mozpointerlockchange', lockChangeAlert, false);


  let player = new THREE.Object3D()
  player.position.set(0, 0, 0)

  player.add(camera)
  scene.add(player)


  function updatePosition(event) {
   camera.rotation.order = 'YZX'
   let { movementX, movementY } = event
   let rotateSpeed = 0.002
   player.rotation.y -= movementX * rotateSpeed
   camera.rotation.x -= movementY * rotateSpeed
   camera.rotation.x = Math.max(-Math.PI / 2, Math.min(camera.rotation.x, Math.PI / 2))
   camera.rotation.order = 'XYZ'
  }

  function lockChangeAlert() {
   if (document.pointerLockElement == renderer.domElement) {
    document.addEventListener("mousemove", updatePosition, false)
   } else {
    document.removeEventListener("mousemove", updatePosition, false)
   }
  }

  let keys = {}
  function keyDown(event) {
   keys[event.key] = true
  }
  function keyUp(event) {
   delete keys[event.key]
  }

  document.onkeydown = keyDown
  document.onkeyup = keyUp

  function update() {
   let moveSpeed = 0.05

   cube.rotation.x += 0.01
   cube.rotation.y += 0.01

   if(keys["w"]) {
    player.position.x -= Math.sin(player.rotation.y) * moveSpeed
    player.position.z -= Math.cos(player.rotation.y) * moveSpeed
   }
   if(keys["s"]) {
    player.position.x += Math.sin(player.rotation.y) * moveSpeed
    player.position.z += Math.cos(player.rotation.y) * moveSpeed
   }

   if(keys["d"]) {
    player.position.x += moveSpeed * Math.sin(player.rotation.y + Math.PI / 2)
    player.position.z += moveSpeed * Math.cos(player.rotation.y - Math.PI / 2)
   }
   if(keys["a"]) {
    player.position.x -= moveSpeed * Math.sin(player.rotation.y + Math.PI / 2)
    player.position.z -= moveSpeed * Math.cos(player.rotation.y - Math.PI / 2)
   }

  }

  function draw() {
   renderer.render(scene, camera)
  }

  function loop() {
   update()
   draw()

   requestAnimationFrame(loop)
  }

  loop()
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

After meshing around a little bit, i did this and got it working fine

```
if(keys["d"]) {
    player.position.x += moveSpeed * Math.sin(rotation + Math.PI / 2)
    player.position.z += moveSpeed * Math.cos(rotation + Math.PI / 2)
}
if(keys["a"]) {
    player.position.x += moveSpeed * Math.sin(rotation - Math.PI / 2)
    player.position.z += moveSpeed * Math.cos(rotation - Math.PI / 2)
}
```